# How to check if a method from a service is called or not in Jasmine unit testing without using spyOn in Angular?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a method say performAnalytics() in a service say analyticsService that is called when you click on a specific element in the HTML.
I am writing unit test cases and trying to cover the code using jasmine.
I trigger the click event on the HTML element
`testElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));`.
The performAnalytics() gets called the code coverage is successful.
The performAnalytics method forms an object and inturn calls another method from some other service.

Now I want to write an expectation as follows

`expect(analyticsService.performAnalytics()).toHaveBeenCalled()`

For this to work I need to use spyOn on the method as follows

`spyOn<any>(analyticsService, 'performAnalytics');`

But if I use spyOn, the method performAnalytics will be mocked and will not be executed in real. Hence the code coverage of the method performAnalytics() is not successful.

Please help. I am new to Angular. Any other alternative to spyOn to use toHaveBeenCalled() ?

If I don't write the expectation, and simply trigger the click event to cover the code it will show warning as 'SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave your `expect` as is and use [callThrough](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callThrough%3C/code%3E) to spy and delegate calls to actual implementation:

```js
spyOn<any>(analyticsService, 'performAnalytics').and.callThrough();
```